# mysqli - fetch several rows applying several where conditions

Tags: mysqli

With only one query I want to fetch specific rows that contains a range of several string values. Is it possible to modify my WHERE to do this?

This is the code for one country but I want to select several rows for several countries. For example: Jamaica, Portugal and Dominica.

```
// Select countries to show
$specific_country = Dominica;

// Select and write SPECIFIC ROWS data
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Country='$specific_country'");
```

This will only get the rows of Dominica but I wanted to use something similar to get Jamaica, Portugal and Dominica but all on the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE Country IN('Jamaica', 'Portugal', 'Dominica')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e61ee/2)** demo

In php

```php
$countries = array('Jamaica', 'Portugal', 'Dominica');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Country IN('". implode("','", $countries) . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and super well explained! You are the best! :) Thanks